# How to associate polygons with the nearest point on a point layer? (Or ... how do I assign a postal area to a salesman?)

Tags: qgis, spatial-statistics

I have a polygon layer of postal code areas and I want to use them to create sales territories based on where our sales people are based. So I assume that I need to work out for each of the polygons which is the nearest point on the sales person point layer. I suppose that I could do this on the nearest part of the polygon or the centroid ... I don't think it would make much difference.

Can someone point me in the direction of what this type of analysis is even called?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can check out [Hub Distance](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/) in MMQgis.

> The hub distance tool iterates through each feature on the source
>   points layer and finds the closest "hub" from the destination hubs
>   layer based on Ellipsoidal distance. The output is a shapefile
>   containing all the attributes from the source layer along with a
>   distance field and the name of the hub based on an attribute selected
>   in the Hub Layer Name Attribute box.

[image: hub]
[image: hub]

i hope it helps you...

Comment: recommended solution - good investment to learn this.

Comment: Thanks Aragon. I eventually got this right once I put the layers in the right order!!!